# Get an error when trying to set the build version with the AssemblyInfo Task

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, msbuild-task, assemblyinfo

I've added the AssemblyInfo Task reference to my C# project file (VS2008 .NET 3.5), but when I build I get the following error

> The "AssemblyInfo" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>   System.ArgumentException: version
>   Parameter name: The specified string
>   is not a valid version number    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Extras.Version.ParseVersion(String
>   version)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Extras.AssemblyInfo.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy
>   engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket,
>   TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask,
>   ITask task, Boolean&
>   taskResult)

My assemblyinfo file has these two attributes:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting AssemblyVersion to "1.0.*" and commenting the AssemblyFileVersion line.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

If it still doesn't work, you could try using the AssemblyInfo task of [MSBuild Community Task](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

```
<AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"  
              OutputFile="AssemblyInfo.cs" 
              AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0" 
              AssemblyFileVersion="1.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: I get this error(OutputFile not supported)...  C:\AAROOT\csharpprojects\toolbar\project.build(17,19): error MSB4064: The "OutputFile" parameter is not supported by the "AssemblyInfo" task.